# Connect kubernetes with Jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, multibranch-pipeline

I am trying to deploy container using helm from Jenkins pipeline. I have install Kubernetes plugin for jenkins and provided it local running kubernetes URL and the config file in credentials. When I am doing `'Test connection'`, it is showing`'Connected to Kubernetes 1.16+'`.

But when I run helm install command from pipeline it gives error

```
Error: Kubernetes cluster unreachable: the server could not find the requested resource
```

Note: I am able to do all operation using CLI and also from Jenkins pipeline by using `withCredentials` and passing cred file variable name(created in jenkins credentials). I just want to do this without wrapping it inside `'withCredentials'` .

Both Jenkins and kubernetes are running seperately on windows 10. Please help

Comment: What version of `helm` are you using? Can you share the full helm command that you tried?

Comment: @Bimal helm install app-name charts-dir -n nsname --set image=imagename --set nodePort=31200

Answer (score 0):

Helm uses kubectl config file. I'm using an step like this.

```
steps {
        container('helm') {
          withCredentials([file(credentialsId: 'project-credentials', variable: 'PULL_KEYFILE')]) {
            sh """
            gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file=${PULL_KEYFILE} --project project-name
            gcloud container clusters get-credentials cluster-name --zone us-east1
            kubectl create namespace ${NAMESPACE} --dry-run -o yaml | kubectl apply -f -
            """
            helm upgrade --install release-name .
          }
        }
      }
```